# Python- can't install non-conda package

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed anaconda2-4.4.0 in path `/opt/anaconda` and add it as my Pycharm interpreter and all things went well until I needed to install non-conda python package in this [link](https://codeload.github.com/roshan-research/hazm/zip/refs/heads/master). I installed it using `pip` command and it was in my Python packages using command `pip list`, But the problem is that package was not included in Conda, as I checked using command `conda list` and I couldn't import it in my project that uses anaconda as Python interpreter as well.
I try installing my package offline using command `conda install --offline Downloads/hazm-master.tar.bz2`, But it was errorful.

```
KeyError: Dist(_Dist__initd=True, channel=u'<unknown>', dist_name=u'hazm-master', name=u'hazm', version=u'master', build_string=u'', build_number=0, with_features_depends=None, base_url=u'file:///home/soheil/Downloads', platform=None)
```

How can I add my desired package on anaconda packages?

Comment: To summarize: you've successfuly installed the package from GitHub using pip, when you run `pip list` the package shows up, when you run `conda list` it doesn't, you can't import the package either, you've made sure that you're using the correct `pip` (the one specific to your Anaconda install/virtual environment) and trying to `conda install --offline` the donwloaded file fails (which makes sense because I don't think conda can install regular python packages). Am I getting this right? If so this makes no sense. -.-'

Comment: @orangeInk you're right. The problem was I didn't create an environment as @Sraw said. Now I created an environment and then install my desired package using `pip` and all thing are well!

Comment: Now according to this scenario can anyone post an answer to clarify for future readers!

Comment: It is mentioned in `conda docs`.I added that link.See my edit

Comment: While I'm happy you found a way to make it work for you it still doesn't explain why it wasn't working to begin with. It's certainly adviced to use virtual environments but you should be able to install packages to the Anaconda root just fine. Curious...

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `pip` to do that. So what should work is

```
Conda.add("pip")
pip = joinpath(Conda.BINDIR, "pip")
run(`$pip install -e 'git+https://github.com/sobhe/hazm`)
```

On windows is might be

```
pip = joinpath(Conda.SCRIPTDIR, "pip")
# On UNIX, Conda.SCRIPTDIR == Conda.BINDIR
```

**EDIT**

However; You can also catch up [**this**](https://web.archive.org/web/20181106130348/https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-non-conda-packages) link to install the `non-conda` packages(Thanks to **@Sraw's** assistance)

Comment: Where should I run this commands? On terminals? Cause I run the first line `Conda.add("pip")` and It errors `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"pip"'`

Comment: Is `pip` installed on your system?

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Okay so that was for `OSX`.I am looki!!!ng for it on ubuntu why `Conda.add` not working

Comment: Could you type `which pip` in your console and tell us if it points to a location in your Anaconda directory?

Comment: Sorry;@orangeInk but was this comment for me?

Comment: That was for @soheil Sorry, should've been more clear.

Comment: I don't think this is the critical question. There should be a `pip` in conda environment, and user should install their non-conda packages use this `pip`. In other word, they should activate environment first. `source activate env_you_use` => `pip install packages_you_want`

Comment: Did you set the root environment as your Pycharm interpreter or a created one?

Comment: @Soheil Please refer this link for your `environment env` problem.Hope it might help:https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html

Comment: @soheil to avoid any further confusions have you ran your last command with `--offline` included as: `conda install  --offline  Downloads/hazm-master.tar.bz2`

Comment: @user7571182 Hi, the link in your answer is obsolete. Can you, please, update it?